# I can not make library overrides work for probs making such as cables with splines

Tags: instances, library-overrides

I am making a range of probs for a production. When it comes to large scenes I used a lot X-Ref or instancing and referencing.

In Blender the (new) features for this is "library overrides".

You can reference object blocks and data blocks but also override them.
Though I can not get it to work.

Here is a short explanation of the issue:

[Video showcasing the cable tray and issue at hand](https://youtu.be/xeKPnNZgNfk)

[image]

Any help and best practice is very much appreciated.

Comment: You should describe the steps you did as you leave us guessing.    Perhaps References.001 is Linked into this file as a Collection?   Then you selected the Collection and did an Object -> Relations -> Make Library Override... ?   What is the Disable in Viewport set to in the original file that you linked, or in this instance?   Then did an Object -> Relations -> Make Local -> ____ ?   (Gracias to Duarte, for removing the (obvious) "Need Help" from the Subject and adding library-overrides to the Tags

Comment: Hey James, perhabs I should have made the video link more obvious. It illustrates exactly that as it is a much better format to see what may be the issue. I saved the file. Opened a new file, linked the scene via import-> link->scene. Then I tried to do exactly what is shown in the blender manual and wento to object -> relations -> make library override. I also tried the same process with linking not the scene but the objects, or the collections or just the mesh mesh data. But none seemed to work. Lastly I tried to just make everything local. But sadly it did not work. Thanks for the help.